# How can I programmatically find the Windows Fax Personal CoverPages folder?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, fax

I'm trying to find the Windows Fax "Personal CoverPages" folder from my application.

On my Win7 machine, it's `C:\Users\USER\Documents\Fax\Personal CoverPages`

But Windows Fax also comes with XP and Vista Ultimate.  I'm pretty sure their folders wouldn't be in the same place.

Is there any way for me to find this folder from my C# code?  I'm already using FAXCOMEXLib Interop to send faxes and I'm trying to find a way to easily look at the user's coverpages.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var coverPagePath =
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments),
"Fax\\Personal CoverPages");
```

Comment: Is that *always* where it will be?  Because XP's faxing program is just "Windows Fax" and 7's is "Windows Fax and Scan," so I was thinking they might store files in actually different folders, not just in folders differing by the normal XP/7 differences.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Not sure.  I thought your question was more about finding the physical location of the "My Documents" folder (which, as you pointed out, is different between XP and Vista/Win7).  I poked around the registry and didn't see it stored anywhere.  You may have to just configure it yourself based on where it exists in each OS.